# How can I add child nodes to selected parent nodes using contextMenuStrip "Add node" item?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

```
static TreeNode Parentnode;
    public void Attack_Trees()
    {
        treeView2.Nodes.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < ThreatEvaluationInstances.Count; i++)
        {
           Parentnode = new TreeNode(ThreatEvaluationInstances.ElementAt(i).Threat1);
            treeView2.Nodes.Add(Parentnode);
        }
    }
    private void addNodeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //How can i implement this
    }
```

This is what I have so far Im able to add all my parent nodes on to the treeview and I also have a contextMenuStrip addeded to the treeview but my goal is that when the user right clicks it will show Add Node (which I already implemented) from there I want to add a child node on the user selected parent node

Comment: Just check the TreeView's SelectedNode property and use that.

Comment: Ok I just did that TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
            treeView2.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(child); but my goal is let user write whatever text than add the child node how can i achieve that. Thanks

Comment: Just make sure SelectedNode isn't null.  Your question didn't have those edit parameters.  Set the TreeView's LabelEdit property to true and then after the node is added, you can have `child.BeginEdit();`